# imported component is not displayed

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i've a component that i import, but its not displayed on the page.

this is my app.js file. i imported the `<player/>`component but it is not getting displayed properly on the browser.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { player } from "./player";

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div>
      <player />
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

this is the contents of the player.js

```
 import React from "react";
 import { Button } from "evergreen-ui";

 export default class player extends React.Component {
 constructor(...args) {
 super(...args);
 this.state = {
  shoot: 0
 };
 }
shoot() {
this.setState.shoot = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3));
}
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>hello there</h1>
    <h1>{this.state.shoot}</h1>
    <Button onClick={() => this.shoot}>Shoot another 
    value</Button>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you've exported your player component as a default export

```
export default class player extemds React.Component
```

But in your import of it in the other file, you're importing it as a named export

```
import { player } from "./player";
```

Try importing it without the curly braces as you would with a default export

```
 import player from "./player";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two mistakes: 
1. Importing the component in the wrong way 
2. Rendering the component in the wrong way

**Solution**

1. The component should be imported without the curly braces
2. The react component "player" is supposed to start with capital letters i.e. it should be renamed as Player

Below is the working code I have tried in my local machine. It only modifies `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Player from "./player"; // imported without curly braces and with capital first letter

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <Player /> {/* Rendering the correct way */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Sidenote**

In `player.js`, you are setting the state in the wrong fashion, it won't work because:

1. `setState` is a method and not a object
2. `this` is not binded with method `shoot`. It will throw error something like "cannot read this of undefined" or something

Modify your `player.js` as following:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "evergreen-ui";

export default class player extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      shoot: 0
    };
  }
  shoot = ()=>{
    this.setState({
      shoot: Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3)),
    });
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>hello there</h1>
        <h1>{this.state.shoot}</h1>
        <Button onClick={() => this.shoot()}>Shoot another
    value</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two main issues:

1) You export as default and then your import is wrong.

If you export as:

```
export default class player extemds React.Component
```

Then you need to import as:

```
import player from "./player";
```

2) Components **must** start uppercase, otherwise React thinks that they are simple HTML tags and not components. 
So you must change `player` to `Player` everywhere